# Anaconda module installs: Error: Could not find Binstar user netcdf

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, netcdf, numba

I have just installed Anaconda, the latest version for Python 2.7. I then tried to add more modules using the conda command, but each time I did so I received an error telling me that the Binstar user named 'netcdf' is not found. To wit:

```
James@LAPTOP ~
$ conda install numba
Fetching package metadata: ....Error: Could not find Binstar user netcdf

James@LAPTOP ~
$ conda install netcdf
Fetching package metadata: ....Error: Could not find Binstar user netcdf

James@LAPTOP ~
$ conda install netCDF4
Fetching package metadata: ....Error: Could not find Binstar user netcdf

James@LAPTOP ~
$ conda install numpy
Fetching package metadata: ....Error: Could not find Binstar user netcdf
```

Can anyone suggest what may be happening here, and/or how to get past this issue?

Comment: did you modify your `.condarc` in any way? Setup any channels?

Comment: Thanks, this was in fact the issue. It took me a while to find my .condarc file, and I'm not sure how it got the netcdf entry added into it, but there it was, and removing it was what fixed this issue. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `netcdf` line from your `~/.condarc` file.

Comment: This fixed me up. Thanks!